# Running OPTICS clustering on ELKI using large geo-dataset

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, data-mining, elki

I am using OPTICSXi with rstartree on ELKI to cluster geo-dataset (latitude&longitude), Gowalla, which includes about 6 million records, but MiniGUI always shows 'java heap space' and 'error:out of memory'.

I used to see an answer of Anony Mousse, in which 1.2 million location data were dealed in 11 minutes, using OPTICSXi on ELKI. i'm so confused. Why ELKI reporting these errors?

Any parameters I need to modify on java platform or ELKI?

[image]

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: I've modified the heap size of JVM,but it does not seem to work

Comment: How much memory *do* you have? The error is an **out of memory error**, probably little we can help you here - you may need more memory (also nothing "confusing" here). Try larger page sizes for the index (smaller pages = more pages = more memory). Try with a subset only - you do not need to *start* with all 6 million, do you? Try to free memory, e.g. by closing eclipse and the browser or using a dedicated Linux server. Use `-Xmx` to use all but a few hundred MB of your available memory on such a machine. Write the result to a file - the SVG visualization will die on this amount of data.

Comment: I have 4G memory. I changed the parameter  -Xmx 3072m, and closed nearly all the unnecessary applications. Now,ELKI is not reporting error when I try with one-sixth subset, but is running for about several hours without any result (I've already closed visualization and chosen to write to a file).

Comment: 4GB is probably too little for all data. What page size & bulk load do you use?

Comment: Page size is changed to 8192, and bulk strategy is MaxExtensionSortTileRecursiveBulkSplit. The running time of that one-six subset is nearly 12 hours.

Comment: Try a smaller epsilon, too. If you choose a too large epsilon, the index does not help anything - worst case it is still quadratic runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard **out of memory** error.

You will have to add more memory, or decrease memory consumption somehow.

You could also try the cover tree (it should need much less memory than the current R*-tree implementation). Make sure to use an appropriate, and small, value of epsilon to benefit from indexing.